# get the cell value and row value in ui-grid in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

How to get cell value and row value in ui-grid?

in ng-grid:

```
 <span ng-click=\"rowClick()\" ng-bind=\"row.getProperty(col.field)\"></span>
```

Like is there any option ui-grid?

could you please some one suggest Thanks in advance !

Comment: what version of ng-grid are you using? how would you like to access the values?

Comment: I am using 3.1.0,  i am getting the josn data from DB, i need set celltemplate value from json data, could you please let me know, if you have any idea, Thanks in advance ! @sdfacre

Comment: It's easy: row / rowData.entity.[yourproperty] .  With the entity property being a JS object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

external event:
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/301_editableOnFocus

or internal:

if u wanna implement it in inside grid, u should change cellTemplate like that:

```
<span ng-click=\"grid.appScope.getProperty(row)\"></span>
```

and define getProperty(...) method

```
$scope.getProperty = function(rowData){
     console.log(rowData);
}
```

grid and row - can be used inside template for

Comment: Hi @un.spike, I have one more doubt, in row data i am getting, check box value is Y or N, how to set the value to that check box, if Y, check box need to checked and if it N it not checked, if don't mine you have any example or any idea, could you please share with me, Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable

{ name: 'isActive', enableCellEdit: true, type: 'boolean'},
type boolean on colDef field
or
if u wanna always display the checkbox u need rewrite cellTemplate